# How to assign different threads to different methods of other class not using main main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, thread-synchronization

Lets say I have a main class `Start.java`

```
public class Start{
    //Here I want to integrate the programs for which i will be needing threads
}
```

and I also have two more classes which contains two different methods.

```
public class ReadUpdateDb {
    public void updateDb(Statement stmt) 
}

public class DbToXls {
    public void dbtoXLS(Statement stmt)
}
```

Here is my problem: I dont how to assign two different threads to the methods `updateDb()` and `dbtoXLS()`.

Also, I want to run `updateDb` after every two hours and `dbtoXLS` once in a day.

Comment: You don't assign different threads to methods; you invoke methods from threads. It looks like you are looking for a `ScheduledExecutorService`, or similar.

Comment: as Andy suggests. You do not need threads for that. You need some sort of scheduling. I personally use spring boot with it's great task scheduling features to do this without too much boilerplate code. However, a simple timer with scheduled tasks could also suffice.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, `ScheduledExecutorService` will do the job. I also suggest to name threads using Guava's `ThreadFactoryBuilder` for example, it will be much easier to debug in the future.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder;

public class Start {

    private static final Integer POOL_SIZE = 2;

    private final ScheduledExecutorService schedExecutor = Executors
                    .newScheduledThreadPool(POOL_SIZE,
                     new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("Schedule-Updater-%d")
                    .setDaemon(true).build());

    public void go() {
        Statement stmt = null;  // construct your statement here
        ReadUpdateDb readUpdateDb = new ReadUpdateDb();
        schedExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> readUpdateDb.updateDb(stmt),
                          0, 2, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        DbToXls dbToXls = new DbToXls();
        schedExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> dbToXls.dbtoXLS(stmt),
                          0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        schedExecutor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i tried doing the above but it shows me below error -

Comment: i tried doing the above but it shows me below error in eclipse saying that "Syntax error on token "updateDb", AssignmentOperator expected after this token" at line                                                        schedExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(readUpdateDb::updateDb, 0, 2, TimeUnit.HOURS);                                                                                                                                                                 also i forgot to mention that those two methods are take parameters just one readUpdate(Statement stmt) and dbtoXLS(Statement stmt)

Comment: @TejasZambre, "also i forgot to mention that those two methods are take parameters" and that is the case. I've updated answer for you.

Comment: No actually i have some oracle queries written in those methods so whenever code starts to execute those queries it comes out of the method and comes back in main so am stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ScheduledExecutorService` or open source implementation like quartz.

ScheduledExecutorService example for running in every 15 min.

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
        .newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void startScheduleTask() {

    final ScheduledFuture<?> taskHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    updateDb();
                }catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); //or loggger would be better
                }
            }
        }, 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
```

QUARTZ Example

```
public class SimpleTriggerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Quartz 1.6.3
        // JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
        // job.setName("dummyJobName");
        // job.setJobClass(HelloJob.class);

        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class)
            .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();

                //Quartz 1.6.3
        // SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger();
        // trigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000));
        // trigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
        // trigger.setRepeatInterval(30000);

        // Trigger the job to run on the next round minute
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
            .withSchedule(
                SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInSeconds(5).repeatForever())
            .build();

        //job2
        JobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob2.class)
                .withIdentity("dummyJobName1", "group1").build();
        Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName1", "group1")
                .withSchedule(
                    SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                        .withIntervalInSeconds(5).repeatForever())
                .build();
        // schedule it
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        //scheduler.scheduleJob(job1, trigger1);

    }
}
```